# jQuery not working with phpfreechat?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am having problems when I call this code in my webpage:

```
<?php $chat->printChat(); ?>
```

This line of code calls the chatroom ( phpfreechat ) that uses prototype.js 1.6.0.2
After I call this, my jQuery.js stops working. But when I call my jQuery.js after the calling of chat the jQuery works but the Chat doesnt seem to work. How can I make both of this javascript work in my webpage? tnx for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `jQuery.noConflict()` because you are using `prototype` so that is conflicting with `jQuery`.

> **Description:** Relinquish jQuery's control of the `$` variable.
>
> Many JavaScript libraries use `$` as a function or variable name, just as `jQuery` does. In `jQuery's` case, `$` is just an alias for `jQuery`, so all functionality is available without using `$`. If you need to use another JavaScript library alongside `jQuery`, return control of `$` back to the other library with a call to `$.noConflict()`. Old references of `$` are saved during `jQuery` initialization; `noConflict()` simply restores them.

#### **[Read More](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)**

**Example**

```
jQuery.noConflict();
   
// Use jQuery via jQuery(...)
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    jQuery("div").hide();
});
```

**OR**

```
var $jQ = jQuery.noConflict();

// Use jQuery via $jQ(...)
$jQ(document).ready(function()

{
    $jQ("div").hide();
});
```

Use the following technique, which allows us to use `$` inside of a block of code without overwriting `$`:

```
(function($) { /* some code that uses $ */ })(jQuery)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how can I relinquish jQuery's control of the $ variable? This is the first time that I encountered this problem.. Thanks.

Comment: @CedricMariano have you checked Read More link..?

Comment: Ow sorry I didnt notice.. Ill come back to you if it will work.. tnx btw.

Comment: Dipesh Parmar the above code makes the whole pages to disappear. I dont why that happen. I use

    var $jQ = jQuery.noConflict();
    // Use jQuery via $jQ(...)
    $jQ(document).ready(function()

    {
    $jQ("div").hide();
    });

after I call all the jQuery libraries except for the prototype.js. is that right?

Comment: I use var $jQ = jQuery.noConflict(); // Use jQuery via $jQ(...) $jQ(document).ready(function() { $jQ("div").hide(); }); after I call all the jQuery libraries except for the prototype.js. is that right?

Comment: @CedricMariano call jQuery before use it...and also load prototype because this code will remove confliction of jQuery and prototype.

Comment: Dipesh Parmar I put this <script>
jQuery.noConflict();

// Use jQuery via jQuery(...)
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    jQuery("div").hide();
});
  </script>

 after I call the phpfreechat chatroom because prototype.js is called when phpfreechat have been printed at the webpage.

Comment: @CedricMariano so whats wrong..?? are you using firebug..??? if yes then what error it showing u.?

Comment: sorry I only use notepad++ for coding and the browser that I am using(Google Chrome) doesnt show errors. After I put that code it only shows a blank webpage

Comment: @CedricMariano so use firefox and get firebug from getfirebug.com and see all the css and javascript error in console.

Comment: Dipesh Parmar Found out the errors.. there are 2.. one is from the CSS

here is the error  

{  $('#jsddm > li').bind('mouseover', jsddm_open)

I think this error is the dropdown list menu that I manually created. How can I fix it? the second one is the TypeError: $(...) is null
[Break On This Error]  

$("#webcam").scriptcam({ This script comes from the plugin scriptcam that doesnt show in the web page when the chat has been called...

Comment: @CedricMariano see that is the reason why above solutions does not worked..??? first of all i you use latest version of jQuery then use .on instead of .bind....and second make sure scriptcam javascript is loaded into document.

Comment: Very thankful to you Dipesh Parmar... I solve the problem in the scriptcam.. as you said I change the $ sign in the script of scriptcam to 'jQuery' and now the Webcam now runs.. in the dropdown menu list which is css what will I use? cheers to u.. and I am very sorry because this is my first time in developing a website..

Comment: @CedricMariano its okay brother....glad to help you...what css you are asking..??

Comment: the problem in CSS error: TypeError: $(...) is null
[Break On This Error]  

{  $('#jsddm > li').bind('mouseover', jsddm_open)

what changes I have to make in order to show my dropdown list menu? You're a lifesaver my thesis defense will be 3 days from now..

Comment: @CedricMariano so use it as  `$jQ('#jsddm > li').bind('mouseover', jsddm_open)` i mean you need to ignore conflicting with prototype..Use code from answer...

Comment: Oh it is the same with the scriptcam. that works perfectly!. Many thanks again. I owe my one major subject to you :)

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to wrap your all jQuery code inside self executing function in which jQuery is passed as argument.

```
(function ($) {

  // Your jQuery code which can safely use `$`
  ..
  ..

}(jQuery));
```

You can also use,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  ...

  //Your jQuery code with which can safely use `$`
  ..

});
```